# What do counts per keV as a unit in alpha decay spectra mean?

Tags: radiation, spectroscopy, elements

I'm reading a paper on superheavy elements. In this paper, they provide a spectra of alpha decays to prove that they have made the element they are researching. The units of the y-axis are Counts/5keV. I know what counts are, and I know what keV means, but I have no idea what the interpretation of them combined in this way could be. A link to the paper is [here](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1021/ic4026766).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, energy-resolving detectors will spit out some signal proportional to the energy of each particle detected. These are fed in to a multi-channel analyzer that determines which energy bin to put the count in to, and increments the count in that bin. Each bin has some energy width. So, you build up the spectra as shown in Figure 3. I will presume either that they set each bin to 5keV (so they are showing actual counts), or normalized to counts per 5keV but actually took the data with a different bin width.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Could you elaborate on what you mean by energy bin?

Comment: One sets up the multichannel analyzer with a certain energy (well, voltage from the detector, really) bin. Say you have a 0-10V signal (in discrete pulses) from your detector, and a 1000 bins. Each bin is then 10mV wide. So, any pulse with a voltage between 5.950 and 5.960V goes in one bin. From 5.960 to 5.970V goes in another. Then you build up a histogram of all the counts, giving the plot in Figure 3 of the paper you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It means counts per 5 keV "bin." So for example there are ≈10 particles between 6000-6005 keV and ≈100 particles between 6080-6085 keV. The 5 keV is the resolution which with they have captured or presented the data.